# Delete blank lines from a file without creating a new file

Tags: ruby, lines

How can I delete blank lines from a file in Ruby without creating a new file?

I read some examples in which files are read line-by-line, and only non-blank lines are written into a new file. Is there an alternative to this approach.

Is there something like sed one-liner?

Comment: `file = 'something.txt'; File.write(file, File.read(file).gsub(/\n+/, "\n"))`. Although it is probably better to read the file line-by-line like you say, so that you can work with large files.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, this did the magic. Can you please put some words to the gsub code. I have normally used it to replace text, are we replacing "\n+" with "\n". I could not get this.

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-gsub).

Comment: You can't *SAFELY* delete blank lines from a file without creating a new one. You could easily create a new file without worrying about problems like "What happens if the code crashes mid-run?". `grep -v ^$ <input >input.new && mv input input.old && mv input.new input` would do it safely also, and would be very fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though a hack: "Opening file removing blanks and writing back to itself", this works:

```
file_name = './blanked.txt'

original = File.open(file_name, 'r') { |file| file.readlines }
blankless = original.reject{ |line| line.match(/^$/) }

File.open(file_name, 'w') do |file|
  blankless.each { |line| file.puts line }
end
```